# Arduino Ethernet client.available() not working

Tags: amazon-ec2, arduino, webserver, ethernet

I eventually want to send a GET request to my Amazon EC2 server, but for now I just need to get the GET request to work in some fashion. To do that, I am trying to send a GET request to google as a test.

I am using a Arduino Uno with an Ethernet shield connected to the internet via DHCP.

My issue is that although client.connect() seems to work, client.available doesn't work either with google or with my EC2 server. Although, if my issue lies elsewhere, please tell me.

I am able to ping google and do a Telnet GET request simulation using:
-telnet www.google.com 80
-GET /search?q=arduino HTTP/1.0

Arduino Code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// Enter a MAC address and IP address for your controller below.
// The IP address will be dependent on your local network:
byte mac[] = { 0x90, 0xA2, 0xDA, 0x0F, 0xD2, 0xAF };

//byte mac[] =   {0xf0, 0x1f, 0xaf, 0x33, 0x62, 0x2f };

IPAddress ip(192,168,1,11);

// initialize the library instance:
EthernetClient client;

//char server[] = "ec2-54-69-168-77.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com";
char server[] = "www.google.com";

double dummyValue = 7.5;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // attempt a DHCP connection:
  Serial.println("Attempting to get an IP address using DHCP:");
  if (!Ethernet.begin(mac)) {
    // if DHCP fails, start with a hard-coded address:
    Serial.println("failed to get an IP address using DHCP, trying manually");
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  }

  Serial.print("My address:");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}

void loop()
{
    // connect to the server
    for(int i = 0;i <100 ; i++) {  
    if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
        // print to serial monitor
        Serial.println("connected...");
        Serial.println("ARDUINO: forming HTTP request message");

        // send data the server through GET request
        //client.print("GET /~sclaybon3/firstdatatest.php?reading=3 HTTP/1.0\r\n");
        client.print("GET /search?q=arduino HTTP/1.0\r\n");
        Serial.println("Get request");
        //client.print(dummyValue);
        //client.print(" HTTP/1.1");
        //client.print("Host: ec2-54-69-168-77.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com\r\n");
        client.print("Host: www.google.com\r\n");
        //Serial.println("Host:www.google.com");
        //client.print("Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
        client.print("\r\n");


        Serial.println("ARDUINO: HTTP message sent");        

        // give server some time to receive and store data
        // before asking for response from it
        delay(1000);

        // get the response from the page and print it to serial port
        // to ascertain that data was received properly
        if(client.available())
        {
            Serial.println("ARDUINO: HTTP message received");
            Serial.println("ARDUINO: printing received headers and script response...\n");

            while(client.available())
            {
                char c = client.read();
                Serial.print(c);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Serial.println("ARDUINO: no response received / no response received in time");
        }

        client.stop();
    }
    } 

    // do nothing forever after:
    while(true);
}
```

Arduino output:

```
Attempting to get an IP address using DHCP:
My address:192.168.1.11
connected...
ARDUINO: forming HTTP request message
Get request
ARDUINO: HTTP message sent
ARDUINO: no response received / no response received in time
```

Comment: Get rid of the `available()` tests altogether, and the sleep, and just call `read().` It will block. I would expect this API has a proper timeout facility: use it.